# Trying to access an attribute inside a nested class from in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, tdd

I am trying to learn test driven development but I ran into such a silly issue and for the life of me I do not understand what is going on. I am following the book clean craftsmanship and am on the bowling example where classes get tested, this book is in java but I rather do python. Here is the example code I have written:

```py
class BowlingGame:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.frames = [Frame for _ in range(10)]

class Frame:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.rolls = [Roll]

class Roll:
    pass
```

and the test suit is:

```
from bowling import BowlingGame, Frame

game = BowlingGame()

def test_game_has_ten_frames():
    assert len(game.frames) == 10
    assert type(game.frames[0]) == type(Frame)
    assert type(game.frames[9]) == type(Frame)

def test_frame_has_atleast_one_roll():
    len(game.frames[0].rolls) == 1
```

the results give:

```
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                   

test_bowling.py .F                                                                                                                                                            [100%]

===================================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________ test_frame_has_atleast_one_roll __________________________________________________________________________

    def test_frame_has_atleast_one_roll():
>       len(game.frames[0].rolls) == (1)
E       AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'rolls'

test_bowling.py:13: AttributeError
============================================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================================
FAILED test_bowling.py::test_frame_has_atleast_one_roll - AttributeError: type object 'Frame' has no attribute 'rolls'
```

I have tested that it is of type frame in the first test. Yet it claims that Frame doesn't have rolls but this doesn't make any sense to me as its the only attribute it has.

Can someone please explain what is happening before I lose my mind?

I have made a Frame class outside of the game and it was able to locate the rolls so I know the attribute exists. Yet when I try to access it from the game class this is when issues are occurring. What in the python is happening ?????

Comment: You created `Frame` _classes_ instead of _objects_. You need `self.frames = [Frame() for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Oh wow, I can not believe I missed that. Starting Tdd is messing with me somehow. Thank you none the less